# why scrollbar resting on top in react native infinite scrolling using react-native-tab-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist, react-native-tab-view

I'm using [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) in my App in which I have 2 tabs. I am loading **Tab** data via API call for creating infinite scroll pagination in side **Tab**, when data is concatenating in my FlatList data from API then each time my **scroll bar reset to top position**. I currently have snack [demo](https://snack.expo.io/@luckyamit/9905d4) like so: https://snack.expo.io/@luckyamit/9905d4

I don't want to reset my scroll bar on top in each API call i have search a lot for this issue but not find my solution. can any one help me to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve it?
For the others, this problem would be caused by [this](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#:%7E:text=IMPORTANT%3A%20Do%20not%20pass%20inline%20functions%20to%20SceneMap%2C%20for%20example%2C%20don%27t%20do%20the%20following%3A).

If you use `SceneMap` in `renderScene` property, you **should not pass inline function**. It triggers re-rendering so that the scroll position goes to top again.

Try to make them components instead of inline functions.
Just do not use `SceneMap` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix by replace the renderscene inline by putting the logic inside only.

yes this is a prob

i replaced to the following code

```
 renderScene={({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'feed':
        return FirstRoute();
        case 'groups':
       return SecondRoute();
     }
   }}
```

and i was able to fix the scroll to top issue