# React Native FlatList returned from a function or const rerenders from the top when an item is interacted with

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to put a flatlist checklist into a react native tab view, to do that you need to declare the flatlist as a const so it can be used like . Unfortunately whenever I click on an item at the bottom of the list it pops back to the top and rerenders the list. This problem doesn't occur when a flatlist is rendered directly into your components render function.

I've made a simplified version of what I mean.
https://snack.expo.io/ecO7YYlVZ Is the version where clicking an item pops to the top
https://snack.expo.io/1iQ!ILk4B Is the version where clicking an item doesn't pop to the top.

The only difference between the two is the not working version is like this

```
    const Dat = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.container}
      data={rowsData}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={extractKey}
    />
  );
};
return <Dat />;
```

Whereas the working version is like this

```
    return (
  <FlatList
    style={styles.container}
    data={rowsData}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={extractKey}
  />
);
```

EDIT: I need to have the flatlist in a way that I can add it to a tab using react-native-tab-view: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Comment: Why not use the working and not weird version?

Comment: Is it the problem with android? working fine on the ios in snack you shared.

Comment: @D10S I want to use the flatlist inside a tab view using this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar Did you scroll all the way to the bottom before you tried to click? this will only be visible if you scroll so the top of the list is off screen. I've just tried in the ios simulator and could reproduce, although the list almost fully fits on the screen so the effect is only slightly visible, if you try web or android it's more pronounced

Answer (score 2):

Dat component must be outside of render()
because it reinitializes the whole component and then rerenders that
which cause that behavior

instead, when you create a component outside of the render(), the component itself does not reinitialize only data updated

Your Dat component

```
const Dat = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.container}
      data={rowsData}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={extractKey}
    />
  );
};
```

Check the example with the outside of render()

https://snack.expo.io/@jsfit/flatlist

Comment: Perfect! thanks this is exactly what I've been looking for